# Questions about Predicate Logic in relation to a Word Problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am struggling to undersand Predicate Logic and my teacher gave me an interesting problem that is just a little confusing. I am unsure what I need to exactly describe these situations.  I gave it a go but I would appreciate any insights into what I might be doing wrong.

> You are writing a program that keeps track of movies and actors. The
> situation can be described using the following predicates:
>
> - R(M,Y) is true if movie M was released in year Y.
> - S(A,M) is true if actor A appears in movie M.
> - H(M) is true if the movie M was a hit!
>
> Use these predicates to state the following facts:
>
> - (a) Actor “A” has appeared in at least one hit.
> - (b) Actor “A” has appeared in at least two hits.
> - (c) Actors “A1” and “A2” have appeared together in the same movie.
> - (d) All the movies that Actor “A” appears in are hits.
> - (e) Actor “A” appears in all the hits released in ”2020”.

My solutions so far:

- a. (∃x) S(A,M) →  H(M)
- b. (∃x) S(A,M) → H(M) ∧ H(M)
- c. (∃x) S(A_1,M) ∧ S(A_1,M)
- d. (∀x) S(A,M) →  H(M)
- e. (∀x) S(A,M) →  H(M) in 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please first read Point $0$ in [this other
  Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4243674/21813) regarding
  quantification scoping, because a similar issue arises throughout
  your attempts; for example, $$(\exists x) P\to Q$$ actually means
  $$(\exists x P)\to Q$$ instead of the intended $$\exists x (P\to
     Q).$$
- > (a) Actor “A” has appeared in at least one hit.
  >
  > > a. $(∃x) S(A,M) →  H(M)$

  $∃a∃m \big(S(a,m) \land  H(m)\big)$

  > (b) Actor “A” has appeared in at least two hits.
  >
  > > b. $(∃x) S(A,M) → H(M) \land H(M)$

  $∃a∃m_1∃m_2 \big(S(a,m_1) \land S(a,m_2) \land  H(m_1) \land  H(m_2)
     \land m_1\neq m_2\big)$

  > (c) Actors “A1” and “A2” have appeared together in the same movie.
  >
  > > c. $(∃x) S(A_1,M) \land S(A_1,M)$

  $∃a_1∃a_2∃m \big(S(a_1,m) \land S(a_1,m)\big)$

  > (d) All the movies that Actor “A” appears in are hits.
  >
  > > d. $(∀x) S(A,M) →  H(M)$

  $∃a∀m \big(S(a,m) →  H(m)\big)$

  > (e) Actor “A” appears in all the hits released in ”2020”.
  >
  > > e. $(∀x) S(A,M) →  H(M) in 2020$

  $∃a∀m \big(\big(R(m,2020) \land H(m)\big) → S(a,m)\big)$