# Did I correctly translate the premises?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, logic-translation

Premises: **A car in the garage has an engine problem** and **Every car in the garage has been sold**.
Conclusion: **A car has been sold has an engine problem**.

Are my premises and proof correct?

[image]

Comment: 2) must be: $\forall x (Px \to Rx)$

Comment: Why (1)  is not this ∃x (Px → Rx) ? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Because it is correct $\exists x (Px \land Qx)$. See [Restricted quantifier](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Restricted_quantifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second premise ought to instead be: $$\forall x(P(x)\to R(x)).$$

This [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232992/21813) explains why $∃x(P(x)∧Q(x)),$ yet $∀x(P(x)→R(x)).$